# Undefined variable from import: SRGB

Tags: python, variables

So i'm having a hard time trying to understand where my problem might come from.

This is the code i'm using :

```
import glob
import json
import warnings
import copy
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import partial
from tqdm import tqdm
import colorspacious
import numpy as np
from skimage import draw, img_as_float
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.color import gray2rgb
from skimage.util import crop
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from scipy.cluster import vq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


options = {'imread': {},
           'perceptual': {"name": "J'a'b'",
                          "ciecam02_space": colorspacious.CIECAM02Space.sRGB,
                          "luoetal2006_space": colorspacious.CAM02UCS},
           'rgb': 'sRGB1'}
```

*Full code is available here : https://github.com/danielballan/photomosaic/blob/master/photomosaic/photomosaic.py*

This is the (only) error I get (line 23) :

Undefined variable from import: SRGB

All the packages are well installed. I'm using Eclipse & Python 3.9.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Undefined variable from import: SRGB` That doesn't look like a Python error.  Is it from your IDE?

Comment: I'm on Eclipse, how could i solve it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your error it look like your script must try to call SRGB at your line 23th (make sure your code at line 23th is : )

```
"ciecam02_space": colorspacious.CIECAM02Space.sRGB,
```

not

```
"ciecam02_space": colorspacious.CIECAM02Space.SRGB,
```

maybe your code is different from your preview code please check that first.

But if it like the preview please check colorspacious's Docs: https://colorspacious.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

I try your code with Python3.9.0 with Libs version:

> ### colorspacious version 1.1.2
>
> ### numpy         version 1.19.4

Comment: Thanks very much, i tried but unfortunately still the same issue. I have same version for colorspacious and for numpy i have the 1.20.3